# Objective C - Accessing UINavigationController from TabController application

Tags: objective-c

How can I access the UINavigationController from the AppDelegate class in a UITabBarController application?

Like when I'm in a section within the UITabBarController item, I can do self.navigationController.

However, that doesn't exist in the AppDelegate.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no correspondence between navigation controller and app delegate the way there is between navigation controller and the view controllers under it. If your app delegate sets up the navigation controller for a given tab item, it can certainly keep a reference to it in a property or ivar, but you'll need to manage that yourself.